# How can I install usbip on Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I am trying to install usbip on Ubuntu 14.04.2 server. I successfully ran this command:

```
apt-get install usbip
```

Next when I am trying to install the driver by running  `modprobe usbip`, I get the following error

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbip not found.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Voting to close: Since 14.04, usbip has been added to the Linux kernel. Both the question and answer will mislead users of newer releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 The solution to that problem is for another answer to be posted explaining the current situation (with references if possible).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such module like `usbip`. In recent kernel if compiled with:

```
CONFIG_USBIP_CORE=m
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD=m
CONFIG_USBIP_HOST=m
```

You should have `usbip-core`, `usbip-host` and `vhci-hcd`. To set host side please use:

```
sudo modprobe usbip-core
sudo modprobe usbip-host
sudo usbipd -D
```

Then you can start binding USB device. If you want to setup client side:

```
sudo modprobe vhci-hcd
```

More information you can find on my [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20160403200320/http://blog.3mdeb.com/2015/10/27/linux/)

Comment: $ sudo usbipd -D
usbip err: stub_driver.c:  33 (open_sysfs_stub_driver) usbip_common_mod.ko and usbip.ko must be loaded

** (process:1246): ERROR **: driver open failed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Comment: @Bruno: have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/647071/125886), there's a bug with Ubuntu and different packages make this work.