# USB/IP Kernel modules are missing.

Tags: wireless, server, usb, 15.04, ip

I wish to utilize the USB/IP project for school project, but I am having trouble starting the host. We are attempting to send signals from accessibility devices for children with extreme motor disabilities such as (C.P.) over WiFi to a server. The server would then emulate the hardware normally connected directly to the computer the student is working with.

I have read the following post: [Share USB drive over network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612355/share-usb-over-network/612491#612491)

The kernal modules listed are not build into the the kernal. usbip-host and usbip-core are, but when usbipd -D is run to activate the daemon, there is fatel error requiring the modules listed in the above post.

This project will require multiple USB/IP connections. Does anyone have a solution for this or an alternative software. I could only find commercial solutions. Thank you!

```
tyler@tyler-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo modprobe usbip-core usbip-host

tyler@tyler-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo usbipd -D
usbip err: stub_driver.c:  33 (open_sysfs_stub_driver)
usbip_common_mod.ko and usbip.ko must be loaded

** (process:11490): ERROR **: driver open failed
tyler@tyler-Latitude-E6410:~$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/898003) in Ubuntu.

The fix appears to be:

> Uninstall usbip package if you've installed it.
>
> On trusty, install linux-tools-generic-lts-utopic. I can't seem to
>   find a package that will create a binary, but you can run the binary
>   manually from /usr/lib/linux-tools/. As of this writing it's
>   /usr/lib/linux-tools/3.16.0-23-generic/usbip. NOTE, I am running the
>   HWE utopic kernel on my trusty box.
>
> On utopic or vivid install linux-tools-generic. usbip is registered as
>   a binary in this case, you can use directly with 'usbip'.

Comment: Wow. You are the man! Thank you.  usbip and usbipd are already in /usr/lib/linux-tools. It appears multiple times actually? Do you know why? I'm still quite new to linux. @levlaz

Comment: the answer has changed for 18.04 bionic and beyond. This package hasn't been maintained.